# Comparing several ways to inject configuration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am learning Dependency Injection provided by .net core.
So far, I have known 5 ways as follows.

```
// 0
sc.AddSingleton(configuration);

//1
sc.Configure<ServiceOption>(_ => configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceOption)).Bind(_));

//2
sc.Configure<ServiceOption>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceOption)));

//3
sc.AddOptions<ServiceOption>()
.Bind(configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceOption)));

//4
sc.Configure<ServiceOption>(_ => _.ID = "from hard code");
```

## Question

The last one (#4) is not so interesting to me, so let ignore it.
I want to know, when do we need to use each of the remaining ones?

Here is the source code.

`appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "ServiceOption": {
    "ID": "from appsettings.json"
  }
}
```

Code:

```
interface IService
{
    void Do();
}

class Service : IService
{
    readonly ServiceOption option;
    readonly IConfigurationRoot configuration;

    public Service(IOptionsMonitor<ServiceOption> option)
    {
        this.option = option.CurrentValue;
    }

    public Service(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void Do(){}
}

class ServiceOption
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}



class Program
{
    private static readonly IConfigurationRoot configuration;

    static Program()
    {
        configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .Build();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        using (ServiceProvider sp = RegisterServices())
        {
            sp.GetRequiredService<IService>().Do();
        }
    }

    static ServiceProvider RegisterServices()
    {
        ServiceCollection sc = new ServiceCollection();
        sc.AddTransient<IService, Service>();

        int selector = 0;

        switch (selector)
        {
            case 0:
                sc.AddSingleton(configuration);
                break;
            case 1:
                sc.Configure<ServiceOption>(_ => configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceOption)).Bind(_));
                break;
            case 2:
                sc.Configure<ServiceOption>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceOption)));
                break;
            case 3:
                sc.AddOptions<ServiceOption>()
                .Bind(configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceOption)));
                break;
            default:
                sc.Configure<ServiceOption>(_ => _.ID = "from hard code");
                break;
        }

        return sc.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `sc.AddSingleton(configuration);`

   This registers a single instance of the class. This is useful when you don't want the consuming code to have to know about `Microsoft.Extensions.Options`. Another common scenario is when you are not going to use the features provided by the Options pattern.
2. `sc.Configure<ServiceOption>(_ => configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceOption)).Bind(_));`

   This allows you to use a function for the configuration of the options. The syntax you used, however, is quite weird since you are just binding to the already built Configuration.
3. `sc.Configure<ServiceOption>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceOption)));`

   This does the same as above, but binds directly to the Configuration instance.
4. `sc.AddOptions<ServiceOption>().Bind(configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceOption)));`

   This just gives you an `OptionBuilder<T>` which you can use to call `Bind`, `Configure` and `PostConfigure` in a single fluent call.

Comment: Plus one. Sorry, could you let me know how to properly use the second case?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity The way you used it isn't an incorrect one. You normally use that syntax for something like `sc.Configure<ServiceOption>(so => { so.SomeVariable = "bla"; }`

Comment: Oh it is just the hard coded version that has been excluded in my question.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Not necessarily hard-coded, you could do whatever you want in that function, though I wouldn't call a database there :)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is to add an additional option that was excluded

```
//bind to an object graph using `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>`
ServiceOption setting = configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceOption)).Get<ServiceOption>();
//adding that to the service collection as needed
sc.AddSingleton(setting);
```

> `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` binds and returns the specified type. `Get<T>` is more convenient than using `Bind`.

In the above the option can be explicitly injected into dependents

```
public Service(ServiceOption option) {
    this.option = option;
}
```

Its reasoning follows similar to an already provided answer if you do not want to couple your dependent code directly to framework related concerns.

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core: **Bind to an object graph**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-to-an-object-graph)

Ideally you wouldn't want to be injecting `IConfiguration` or `IOptions` if you do not want your application code taking on unnecessary dependencies on framework abstractions.